# Meaning of "individual worker"

Tags: meaning

Is "individual worker" a definite position of it just means "one employee"?
The context:

> The cost of hiring and retraining workers has produced various estimates. The Institute for Research on Labor and Employment at the University of California–Berkeley noted in a 2010 working paper that average replacement costs for an individual worker averaged about $4,000 overall, and about $2,000 for blue collar and manual labor workers. Costs were as high as $7,000 for professional and managerial employees.

Comment: It's simply one person who is a member of the workforce being discussed.

Answer (score 1):

"***[Individual](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/individual)*** worker" refers to a *single worker*, as a unit:

> - by or for one person: *individual work; an individual portion.* (AHD)
> - of, relating to, characteristic of, or meant for a single person or thing. (Collins)

- It is $4,000 estimated cost for the replacement of an individual worker. They are talking about the opportunity cost of retaining vs replacing workers. – The $4,000 is an average replacement cost which includes both blue collar workers and professional and managerial employees – Josh61 3 hours ago

Comment: Thanx, but doens't this seem improbable? 4000 for to train 1 person?

Comment: @AlinaSaidova - $4,000 more or less represents a global expense corresponding to 15 man-days (*working days*). It doesn't seem that far from what we can imagine for recruitment, training and lower efficiency at the beginning.